# Can you reverse order a string in one line with LINQ or a LAMBDA expression

Tags: c#, linq, string, lambda

Not that I would want to use this practically (for many reasons) but out of strict curiousity I would like to know if there is a way to reverse order a string using LINQ and/or LAMBDA expressions in **one line of code**, without utilising any framework "Reverse" methods.

e.g.

```
string value = "reverse me";
string reversedValue = (....);
```

and reversedValue will result in "em esrever"

**EDIT**
Clearly an impractical problem/solution I know this, so don't worry it's strictly a curiosity question around the LINQ/LAMBDA construct.

Comment: Im confused....why don't you want to use the Array.Reverse method?

Comment: how is a LINQ or lambda any better than the more than adequate string methods?

Comment: @Mitch - I was trying to produce a problem for my team thinking it was possible, and got stuck

Comment: ...and that will help your Team how?

Comment: All these limitations! Is it homework?

Comment: I can write a compiler on **one line of code**. but don't expect it to fit on 80 columns...

Comment: *using LINQ and/or LAMBDA expressions but without utilising any framework "Reverse" methods.* What does that mean? The Linq methods are in the framework.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't see a practical use for this but just for the sake of fun:

```
new string(Enumerable.Range(1, input.Length).Select(i => input[input.Length - i]).ToArray())
```

Comment: @Mehrdad, don't worry I wouldn't use it practically but was trying to satisfy personal curiosity.

Answer (score 31):

Well, I can do it in one very long line, even without using LINQ or a lambda:

```
string original = "reverse me"; char[] chars = original.ToCharArray(); char[] reversed = new char[chars.Length]; for (int i=0; i < chars.Length; i++) reversed[chars.Length-i-1] = chars[i]; string reversedValue = new string(reversed);
```

(Dear potential editors: do *not* unwrap this onto multiple lines. The whole point is that it's a single line, as per the sentence above it and the question.)

However, if I saw anyone avoiding using framework methods for the sake of it, I'd question their sanity.

Note that this doesn't use LINQ at all. A LINQ answer would be:

```
string reverseValue = new string(original.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Avoiding using Reverse, but using OrderByDescending instead:

```
string reverseValue = new string(original.Select((c, index) => new { c, index })
                                         .OrderByDescending(x => x.index)
                                         .Select(x => x.c)
                                         .ToArray());
```

Blech. I like Mehrdad's answer though. Of course, all of these are far less efficient than the straightforward approach.

Oh, and they're all wrong, too. Reversing a string is more complex than reversing the order of the code points. Consider combining characters, surrogate pairs etc...

Comment: Crap. I had an off by one error two times before I did it right, for such an easy problem. I'd avoid my approach at all costs!

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I don't consider it a one liner if a statement terminator ; is used and another statement appearing straight after it.

Comment: @Josh: Given that the whole question is somewhat ridiculous IMO, I was taking it absolutely literally. Put it this way - if you went to the line number containing each statement in that code, how many different values would you get? It just shows the value in being precise.

Comment: @Jon, the question was edited to indicate "curiosity" as I wouldn't be using this idea anywhere as I know its an impractical concept. I just wanted to find a non obvious way to perform a known operation and then was thinking of sharing it with my team to see if they could figure it out, although i have now decided to scrap the idea.

Comment: Your last solution (with `OrderByDescending`) is wrong, you need to get rid of the added index, so you need to call `.Select(x => x.c)` before the final `ToArray`.

Comment: Or just `string.Concat(input.Select((c, index) => input[input.Length - index - 1]))`

Comment: You: _Consider combining characters, surrogate pairs etc..._ Yeah, I just added an answer that tries to handle these things, with "text elements" from the `StringInfo`.

Answer (score 22):

```
new string(value.Reverse().ToArray())
```

Comment: Question states 'without utilising any framework "Reverse" methods'.

Comment: Or `string.Concat(value.Reverse())`

Answer (score 7):

```
var reversedValue = value.ToCharArray()
                         .Select(ch => ch.ToString())
                         .Aggregate<string>((xs, x) => x + xs);
```

Comment: You dont need the ToCharArray and Select

Comment: This is the only answer that actually does it in one line with LINQ. Second that you don't need `ToCharArray()`.

Answer (score 5):

Variant with recursive lambda:

```
  var value = "reverse me";
  Func<String, String> f = null; f = s => s.Length == 1 ? s : f(s.Substring(1)) + s[0]; 
  var reverseValue = f(value);
```

LP,
Dejan

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Aggregate` to prepend each `Char` to the reversed string:

```
 "reverse me".Aggregate("", (acc, c) => c + acc);
```

Comment: Don't think so... `acc` goes `""` -> `"r"` -> `"er"` -> `"ver"` -> `...`

Answer (score 2):

```
var reversedValue= "reverse me".Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: Question states 'without utilising any framework "Reverse" methods'.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to one previous post here is a more performant solution.

```
var actual0 = "reverse me".Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (x, y) => x.Insert(0, y)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string Reverse(string word)
{
   int index = word.Length - 1;
   string reversal = "";

   //for each char in word
   for (int i = index; index >= 0; index--)
   {
       reversal = reversal + (word.Substring(index, 1));
       Console.WriteLine(reversal);
   }
   return reversal;
}
```

Quite simple. So, from this point on, I have a single method that reverses a string, that doesn't use any built-in Reverse functions.

So in your main method, just go,

**Console.WriteLine(Reverse("Some word"));**

Technically that's your one liner :P

Answer (score 1):

If we need to support combining characters and surrogate pairs:

```
// This method tries to handle:
// (1) Combining characters
// These are two or more Unicode characters that are combined into one glyph.
// For example, try reversing "Not nai\u0308ve.". The diaresis (¨) should stay over the i, not move to the v.
// (2) Surrogate pairs
// These are Unicode characters whose code points exceed U+FFFF (so are not in "plane 0").
// To be represented with 16-bit 'char' values (which are really UTF-16 code units), one character needs *two* char values, a so-called surrogate pair.
// For example, try "The sphere \U0001D54A and the torus \U0001D54B.". The  and the  should be preserved, not corrupted.

var value = "reverse me"; // or "Not nai\u0308ve.", or "The sphere \U0001D54A and the torus \U0001D54B.". 

var list = new List<string>(value.Length);

var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(value);
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
  list.Add(enumerator.GetTextElement());
}
list.Reverse();

var result = string.Concat(list);
```

Documentation: [MSDN: `System.Globalization.StringInfo` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

```
string str="a and b";
string t="";

char[] schar = str.Reverse().ToArray();

foreach (char c in schar )
{
    test += c.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Ten answers given and you need to add another one? Apart from that, something that always applies to code-only answers is: give a brief explanation. Finally, the question clearly states *without utilising any framework "Reverse" methods*.